# focusing on a particular div using jquery

Tags: jquery

html code is this:

```
<div id="div1" class="all"> </div>
<div id="div2" class="all"> </div>
<div id="div3" class="all"> </div>
<div id="div4" class="all"> </div>
<div id="div5" class="all"> </div>
<div id="div6" class="all"> </div>
<div id="div7" class="all"> </div>
```

I am hiding and showing divs in jquery as below:

```
$(function () {

                 $('#div1').click(function () {

                     $('#div1').hide();    
                         $('#div2').show();  
                 });


                 $('#div2').click(function () {
                     $('#div2').hide();
                       $('#div1').show();
                });
    });
```

on the second part of the div1.show(); I like have browser screoll to div1. Since the page is very populated, it will be nice to go to the original div before clicked.

Comment: what do u mean the DIV should have focus? you mean scroll to it?

Comment: @Sajjan Sarkar, yes, scroll to

Comment: Not tried sdepont's code but I know Darren's code works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to scroll to the div - you would do this using animate.

there is a very good answer with example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8082364/scroll-to-div-jquery-specific-position)

It would be good to use that [plugin](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/) @sdespont recommended. It can target a DOM element (see first examples on that page) you would be able to store what div in a variable and then go to that DOM element when needed.

**so, pseudo code example - this hasn't been tested, it's just an idea of how it could work**:

```
  var clickedDiv; 
  $("#div1").click(function(){
     clickedDiv = $(this);
     $("#div2").scrollTo();
   });

  $("#div2").click(function(){
     $("#divHome").scrollTo({onAfter:function(){
        if (clickedDiv != null){
            $(clickedDiv).scrollTo()
         }
    }});    
 });
```

Comment: @Darren, I've udpated my post. The page has many divs. clicking on a dive takes you to another div. Clicking that div takes you back. When you are back, I like to scroll to the div that was clicked the first time.

Comment: that's because it's pseudo code - i did say it wasn't tested. I cannot do your work for you for free. this was to give you an idea only. I suggest you see the plugin tutorial for further guide.

Comment: @Downvoter... Care to say why?! Giving no feedback on your action helps no one...